# How to print separately this type of pair?

Tags: python

```
adjacency_list = {
    'A': [('B', 8), ('C', 2), ('D', 14)],
    'B': [('D', 21)],
    'C': [('E', 19)],
    'D': [('E',17), ('F', 13), ('C', 25)],
    'E': [('G', 9), ('F', 5)],
    'F': [('G', 1)]
}
row = adjacency_list.get('F')
for pair in row:
    print(pair)
```

I have this list, I want to print pair value separately, like CPP. I want to print `pair.first` and then `pair.second`.
Which will print `'G'` first and then `1` instead of printing `('G', 1)` together. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Well, how did you already set up the code so that it prints the pairs separately, instead of printing a single, full list with all the pairs in it? What would happen if you tried using that technique again? Make sure you understand that "pairs" are not a separate thing in Python. The `(, , ,)` make what is called a *tuple*, and it can contain *any number of items*, just like a list can. You would understand this if you had followed a proper tutorial from start to finish.

Comment: try to clarify expected output if possible. for example are you expecting like "G 1" or on separate lines like "G" and "1"?

Comment: `pair` is a tuple.  If you don't want Python's default formatting, then you have to do it yourself, like `print("%s%d" % pair)`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple unpacking seems to be enough:

```
>>> for pair in row:
...     print(*pair)
...
G 1
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have some key value pairs?

```
adjacency_list = {
    'A': [('B', 8), ('C', 2), ('D', 14)],
    'B': [('D', 21)],
    'C': [('E', 19)],
    'D': [('E',17), ('F', 13), ('C', 25)],
    'E': [('G', 9), ('F', 5)],
    'F': [('G', 1)]
}
row = adjacency_list.get('F')
for key,value in row:
    print("Key: " + str(key) + " Value: " + str(value))
```

Comment: The keys are all strings.  You don't need `str`.

Comment: F-strings would be useful here. `print(f"Key: {key} Value: {value}")`

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this:

```
adjacency_list = {
    'A': [('B', 8), ('C', 2), ('D', 14)],
    'B': [('D', 21)],
    'C': [('E', 19)],
    'D': [('E',17), ('F', 13), ('C', 25)],
    'E': [('G', 9), ('F', 5)],
    'F': [('G', 1)]
}
row = adjacency_list.get('F')
for (k, v) in row:
    print(f'{k}{v}')
```

In the for loop you can name the elements of the pair, and then print using f-strings for string interpolation using the names you bound the elements of the pair to.